# Javascript Not Working in Modal Window With Render Partial (Yii)

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-booster

I implemented a modal with its content rendered using renderPartial(). However, when I try to call a script inside the modal window (e.g $.blockUI), it doesn't work at all. No errors though.

This is how I rendered the content:

```
echo CJSON::encode($this->renderPartial($view, array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'model' => $model,
    'selectedIds' => $selected,
     ), TRUE, TRUE));
```

Comment: are you doing an ajax call? because otherwise I don't think you need to Json encode it. you registered your script in $view file, right?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing an ajax call. I registered my script also.

Comment: did you register the script you want to run in page that does the ajax call, or where you "renderPartial"d it?

Comment: I registered the script in both.

Comment: @tinyByte may be on to something here about the JSON encoding. Is the result of the ajax call via Firebug or a similar tool what is expected?

Comment: Make sure **only** the scripts you need in the modal window are registered in the response. Eg. do **not** load jQuery again.